# Discounted Value at Simple Interest

Tags: finance

Struggling with this question:

*Mr. A borrows 2000 now and 3000 in 4 months. He agrees to pay X in
6 months and 2X in 8 months (from now). Determine X using a focal
date 8 months from now at simple interest rate r = 12%.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the following cash flows
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
c_t &-2000 & -3000 & x & 2x\\
\hline
t & 0 & 4 & 6 & 8\\
\hline
\end{array}
so at $t=8$ months, putting $i=\frac{12\%}{12}=1\%$ we have
$$
-2000(1+i\times 8)-3000(1+i\times 4)+x(1+i\times 2)+2x=0
$$
that is
$$
-2160-3120+3.02x=0
$$
and then
$$
x=\frac{5280}{3.02}=1748.34
$$

Answer (score 0):

Answer I get is 1,747.47

Essentially you want to find $X$ such that the discounted value of all cash received equals the discounted value of all cash paid. E.g., discounted value today of $100$ at $m$ months time from now at $12$% (p.a.) (simple interest) is $\frac{100}{1+(12\% \times m/12)}$. The rest is a bit of algebra.